# .NET Core Docker Image - Pushed a New Image, EB Does Not Reflect Changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Setup:
- EB with custom domain
- .NET Core 2.2
- Docker Images (deploying via Dockerrun.aws.json file)

I've made some significant changes to my site and have pushed a new Docker image to ECR. Tested the image locally and all is working fine. Once I push to EB, some routes still act as if no changes have taken place. Its like EB or the load balancer has the code cached somewhere. The route its trying to serve up still has literally been removed from the new code, but its still trying to serve it up.

Anyone have any experience with this behavior?